# How to pass password to sudo from environment variable without prompt appearing?

Tags: bash, sudo

How do I pass my password to sudo from an environment variable through stdin without the sudo prompt appearing?

I have tried `$ echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S echo foo` but that returns `[sudo] password for mithic: foo`.
Using the `-n` flag just always returns `sudo: a password is required` (unless I have recently inputted the correct password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really in the environment, I would recommend using the `-A` option instead of `-S`. Write a very small script that writes the value to standard output.

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s' "$PASSWORD"
```

Call it something like `asker` and make it executable

```
chmod +x asker
```

The do the following:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=./asker sudo -A echo foo
```

`-A` makes `sudo` run the executable named by `SUDO_ASKPASS` and read the password from its output.

Comment: Great response but for some reason `printf` always includes the newline character at the end for me (even with `'%s'`) but `echo` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an empty password prompt:

```
printf '%s\n' "$PASSWORD" | sudo -p "" -S echo foo
```